# Finding the distinct directory names using grep or rg

Tags: python, grep, ripgrep

I am new to Linux commands and I am trying to search for a word that say "apple" recursively in a directory and all the directory names that contain the word.

I am using ripgrep(rg) similar to grep to get the file names that have an apple in them

Ex:

```
rg -l "apple"
```

gives me output:

```
a/fruit.c
b/fruit.c
a/fruits.c
a/fruitsnames.c
a/fruity/fruits.c
b/fru/fruit/fru/fr.c
c/frts.c
```

Is there a way that I can only the unique parent folder names?

```
Example output I expect is to get only the folder names:
a
b
c
```

Solution using grep is also good.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `sed` to remove everything from `/`, then use `sort -u` to remove duplicates

```
ripgrep -l apple | sed 's#/.*##' | sort -u
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will give it a try :)
Is there an efficient way to do this, say if you found one "apple" in a file in a directory then we can skip checking all the remaining files in that directory, as we only want to get the directory name? I think it would make it more faster

Comment: Only if there's some way you can tell `ripgrep` to stop searching files once it has found a match.

Comment: Then you could use `for dir in */; do ripgrep <option to stop at first match> -l apple "$dir"; done`

Comment: I can't find a complete list of flags in the ripgrep manual. It just has [Common Options](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#common-options)

Comment: yeah, I also searched for it but couldn't find it. May be we can do it grep i will see. 
Thank you so much :)

Comment: I don't think `grep` has an option like this. It has `-r` for recursive and `-m 1` to stop at the first match, but I think that's per file, not per directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Perl one-liner and `sort -u` so keep unique directories:

```
rg -l "apple" | perl -pe 's{/[^/]+$}{}' | sort -u
```

or to keep only the highest level directories:

```
rg -l "apple" | perl -pe 's{/.*}{}' | sort -u
```